# How to interpret results from an experiment where covariate is influenced by the experimental setup?

Tags: experiment-design, interpretation, ancova, predictor

I am doing study investigating the effect of company's heritage on consumer attitude towards the company/brand. For this purpose I have created two texts:

- one revealing the history of the company,
- and the other one - the control text - revealing some general information about the firm.

My results indicated that the two texts differ not only regarding heritage perception, but also regarding information credibility and believability. So the text with history details is also perceived as more credible. And this is also said to influence the attitude.

My questions are:

1. Can I use the perceived text credibility as covariate in the ANCOVA, although it is measured after the treatment and caused by it?
2. How can I interpret the ANCOVA output in this case? Can I separate both effects - the one of the manipulation and the one of the covariate?
3. Would mediation analysis be one possible solution to check whether the effect of the treatment on my dependent variable is fully mediated by text credibility?

Comment: The question needs to be restricted. The covariate is determined with a view to indicate the extent of relationship between two variables that interact on account of some third factor. Further, there is ambiguity in the questions (3 in number). please clarify the variables.